# how to add json object to a html control as an attribute

Tags: jquery, html, json

Is it possible to place json object data in html contols it self in html file. can i store json object in a html textbox control as a data attribute.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.  You can also do it without relying upon the HTML5 `data-*` attribute(s) by doing something like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/LE9bx/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you enter the data-* attribute as well-formed JSON and access it via $.data() it should work fine.

Answer (score 5):

You can store in `data`:

```
<input type="text" data-myjson="{'foo':false,'baz':'hello'}" />
```

And in jQuery:

```
var myjson = $.parseJSON($('input').data('myjson'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea id="jason_data" style="display:none">{"data1":'"double quotation marks"',"data2":"'single quotation marks'"}</textarea>

var oData = $.parseJSON($('json_data').value);
```

Comment: Functional, but not every elegant...One minor issue could be if you accidentally include that `textarea` in a form (which is common in ASP.NET projects).